# ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(x,y,z)) equivalent in Bigquery legacy SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have a standard SQL query of the following structure

```
SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(x,y,z))
FROM t
GROUP BY a
```

How can write the same query in legacy SQL?

Comment: Why do you want to use legacy SQL for your query? The only similar function is NEST but you can't apply it to multiple columns at once, only individually.

Comment: Due to performance issues - the legacy is faster. I've noticed this issue with NEST, but is there a STRUCT equivalent?

Comment: Can you please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)? If you find that a legacy SQL query is faster than its standard SQL equivalent, it indicates a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to NEST non-leaf fields using Legacy SQL. The only workaround would be to pack x,y,z into a string (for example constructing JSON), then use `NEST` on it, and whenever individual fields are needed, use some string parsing function or Javascript UDF. Needless to say, it is much simpler with Standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Meantime, if you still need to have it in BigQuery Legacy SQL - see simple example below.

BigQuery Standard SQL version

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 11 AS x, 12 AS y, 13 AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS a, 21 AS x, 22 AS y, 23 AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS a, 31 AS x, 32 AS y, 33 AS z
)
SELECT 
  a, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(x, y, z)) AS aa 
FROM t
GROUP BY a
```

BigQuery Legacy SQL version (make sure you set destination table and set flatten result off - otherwise UI will flatten output)

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT a, aa.*
FROM JS( 
  ( // input table 
  SELECT 
    a, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(STRING(x), ';', STRING(y), ';', STRING(z))) AS aa 
  FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS a, 11 AS x, 12 AS y, 13 AS z),
  (SELECT 2 AS a, 21 AS x, 22 AS y, 23 AS z),
  (SELECT 3 AS a, 31 AS x, 32 AS y, 33 AS z)
  GROUP BY a
  ), 
  a, aa, // input columns 
  "[ // output schema 
  {name: 'a', type:'integer'},
  {name: 'aa', type:'record', mode:'repeated', 
  fields: [
    {name: 'x', type: 'integer'},
    {name: 'y', type: 'integer'},
    {name: 'z', type: 'integer'}
    ]}
   ]", 
  "function(row, emit) { // function 
    var aa = []; 
    aa1 = row.aa.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < aa1.length; i++) { 
      aa2 = aa1[i].split(';');
      aa.push({x:parseInt(aa2[0]), y:parseInt(aa2[1]), z:parseInt(aa2[2])}); 
    }; 
    emit({
      a: row.a, 
      aa: aa
      }); 
  }"
)
```